# Random Walker in 3D with Processing

Tags: random, 3d, processing

I am trying to build a random walker in three-dimensional space. So far it works, check the code below. However, in the next step I would like to rotate the entire structure around its own Z axis. I have tried different ideas. Firstly, rotating the camera - with PeasyCam, which unfortunately I didn't get set up correctly. Secondly, to work with a PGraphics layer on which the random walker runs - later I rotate it... but here the image always becomes unintentionally flat. What thought have I overlooked? How could the whole structure be combined and rotated?

```
float x;
float y;
float z;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  x = width/2;
  y = height/2;
  z = -height/4;
 //background(255);
}


void draw() {
  x += random(-10, 10);
  y += random(-10, 10);
  z += random(-10, 10);
  //rotateZ(radians(mouseX));
  pushMatrix();
  rotateX(radians(45));
  push();
  translate(x, y, z);
  push();
  rotateX(radians(90));
  rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
  pop();
  pop();
  popMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of gotchas with your what you're trying to do:

1. There's a single point in space at any given time `(x,y,z)`: if you want to draw the 'trails' of this walker you would need to remember them (store changing values in an array (or `ArrayList`). (You were sort of on the right track with PGraphics, but that is simply a flat layer to render into. If you store the values in an array you can then reuse them to render however you'd like).
2. Ideally you'd store the x,y,z values **after** all the nested transformations are applied (e.g. `rotateX()`, `translate()`, etc.). This is where [`modelX()`](https://processing.org/reference/modelX_.html), [`modelY()`](https://processing.org/reference/modelY_.html), [`modelZ()`](https://processing.org/reference/modelZ_.html)

Here's an example using the above notes (converting from local to global coordinates (using modelX,Y,Z) and storing to an array):

```java
import peasy.*;

float x;
float y;
float z;

int numSteps = 300;
PVector[] steps = new PVector[numSteps];
// index of the current step
int currentStep = 0;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  
  x = width/2;
  y = height/2;
  z = -height/4;
  
  // init walker steps (memory)
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSteps; i++){
    steps[i] = new PVector(x, y, z);
  }
  
  new PeasyCam(this, 400);
}

void updateWalker(){
    x += random(-10, 10);
    y += random(-10, 10);
    z += random(-10, 10);
    //rotateZ(radians(mouseX));
    pushMatrix();
      rotateX(radians(45));
      pushMatrix();
        translate(x, y, z);
        pushMatrix();
          rotateX(radians(90));
          //rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
          // use modelX(), modelY(), modelZ() to convert from the local model transformations to global
          steps[currentStep].set(modelX(x, y, z),
                                 modelY(x, y, z),
                                 modelZ(x, y, z));
        popMatrix();
      popMatrix();
    popMatrix();
  
  //increment step index (looping over back to 0 at the end (%))
  currentStep = (currentStep + 1) % numSteps;
}

void drawWalker(){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSteps; i++){
    PVector step = steps[i];
    pushMatrix();
    translate(step.x, step.y, step.z);
    box(10);
    popMatrix();
  }
}


void draw() {
  background(255);
  updateWalker();
  drawWalker();
}
```

Feel free to switch from an array to an [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html).
(It might make adding/removing elements easier in case you want to also update them in a certain order).

Comment: Thank you so much – this helps a lot … If I want to replace the box(); with something like text(); I get really strange artefacts…

Comment: Happy to hear that. The answers you posted address a separate issue/question (regarding text). Although it will require more work, it's worth posting a separate question regarding text specifically and merging and moving your answers bellow there. It will make it easier for everyone else in the future running into a similar issue to find the relevant question and answer directly. Additionally you should try [`textMode(SHAPE);`](https://processing.org/reference/textMode_.html) (switching from text as texture to individual shapes). Best of luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

In a further step I would like to replace the box(); with words (strings) - for this I use an array in which different words are loaded. This works so far, but some words are rendered with a background... so the letters are not free of background. Strange artefacts are rendered. I can't explain why?

```
import peasy.*;
PeasyCam cam;

String[] typos = new String[5];

float x;
float y;
float z;


float size;
int index;

int numSteps = 300;
PVector[] steps = new PVector[numSteps];
// index of the current step
int currentStep = 0;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  x = width/2;
  y = height/2;
  z = -height/4;
  size = height/2;

  typos[0] = "HELLO";
  typos[1] = "TEST";
  typos[2] = "AND";
  typos[3] = "SO";
  typos[4] = "ON";

  index = -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++) {
    steps[i] = new PVector(x, y, z);
  }
  cam = new PeasyCam(this, 0, 0, 0, 400);
}



void updateWalker() {

  background(#c1c1c1);
  x += random(-25, 25);
  y += random(-25, 25);
  z += random(-25, 25);
  pushMatrix();
  rotateX(radians(45));
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x, y, z);
  pushMatrix();
  rotateX(radians(90));

  // use modelX(), modelY(), modelZ() to convert from the local model transformations to global
  steps[currentStep].set(modelX(x, y, z),
    modelY(x, y, z),
    modelZ(x, y, z));
  popMatrix();
  popMatrix();
  popMatrix();

  //increment step index (looping over back to 0 at the end (%))
  currentStep = (currentStep + 1) % numSteps;
}

void drawWalker() {

  for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++) {
    PVector step = steps[i];

    index += 1;
    if (index > typos.length-1) {
      index = 0;
    }
    pushMatrix();
    translate(step.x, step.y, step.z);
    fill(255);
    textSize(200);
    text(typos[index], 0, 0, size, size);
    popMatrix();
  }
}

void draw() {
  updateWalker();
  drawWalker();
}

void mousePressed() {
  if ( mouseButton==LEFT) cam.lookAt(400, 0, 0);
  else cam.lookAt(-400, 0, 0);
  println("Position x: "+cam.getPosition()[0]+
    " y: "+  cam.getPosition()[1]+
    " z: "+  cam.getPosition()[2]);
  println("Rotation x: "+cam.getRotations()[0]+
    " y: "+  cam.getRotations()[1]+
    " z: "+  cam.getRotations()[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with these lines in setup();

```
  hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
  hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_SORT);
  hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_MASK);
```